# How to check if a cell is empty in Google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
var subCategoryAmount = sheet.getRange(row,12,1,1)
```

When there is code like the above, the value of the cell is
Empty, NULL, "", UNDEFINED, etc.
I would like to check for situations where values are not entered into cells.

Can I find out how?

Answer (score 1):

Google Spreadsheet cells contain a value or a formula.  Values can be string, number, boolean or blank ("").  A cell will not contain NULL or UNDEFINED it is simply blank.  Even error in cells are a string such as "#N/A".

If you want to check if it has a value.

```
let subCategoryAmount = sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue();
if( subCategoryAmount === "" ) // then its empty
```

However if its a formula `getValue()` will return blank.  You would need to `getFormula()` which returns a string representing the formula.  But again if there is no formula in the cell but a value than it is not blank.

```
let subCategoryAmount = sheet.getRange(row,12).getFormula();
if( subCategoryAmount === "" ) // then its empty
```

To test if the cell is totally blank use.

```
if( sheet.getRange(row,12).isBlank() ) // then its empty
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
var subCategoryAmount = sheet.getRange(row,12).getValue();
```

You can use:

```
if (!sheet.getRange(row,12).isBlank() {
  var subCategoryAmount = sheet.getRange(row,12).isBlank()
}
```

[ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#isBlank())